# Formatting a date using C# in an MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, format

I have a model with a DateTime property:

```
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I assign that property to a value returned from my database:

```
aModel.EndTime = auction.EndTime.Value;
```

And in my View:

```
<p class="time">@item.EndTime</p>
```

Currently the date is returned as:

```
9/12/2011 --> Month / Day / Year
```

I want it to display as:

```
12/9/2011 --> Day / Month / Year
```

I'm sure the application is displaying the date according to the servers settings, but I do not wish to change that. How can I display the date like I want to in the second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and easy way...

```
<p class="time">@item.EndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</p>
```

I would suggest you store the format string as a config value though so you can easily change it later... or add a way for the user to set their preference

Maybe even do some extension method work...

**Helper class**

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   public static string ToClientDate(this DateTime dt)
   {
      string configFormat = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateFormat"];
      return dt.ToString(configFormat);
   }
}
```

**Config File**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DateFormat" value="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</appSettings>
```

**View**

```
<p class="time">@item.EndTime.ToClientDate()</p>
```

Make sure you View can see the ExtensionMethods class, add a "Using" statement if needed

Answer (score 3):

`<p class="time">@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",item.EndTime)</p>`

Comment: From memory (and other answers) that should be MM rather than mm I think.

Comment: Yeah. You're right. just changed it. Was trying to get the answer in too quickly! ha.

Comment: I mainly noticed because I once deployed production code with mm instead of MM and ever since then I've been hyper-aware. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ToString` method in your view:

```
<p class="time">@item.EndTime.ToString("d/M/yyyy")</p>
```

Comment: That simple huh. Man C# is fantastic.